# Running Functional Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, functional-testing

When i try to run my tests from Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate i get this output

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:05.8242806) ==========

Here is the code:

```
[Then(@"the submitter company list is in alphabetical order")] 
public void ThenTheSubmitterCompanyListIsInAlphabeticalOrder() 
{ 
    List<string> submitterCompanyList = _currentFilingPage.SubmitterCompanyList;
    submitterCompanyList.Should().BeInAscendingOrder(); 
}
```

I have created a .bat file and from there i can run my tests. Please assits me with a way to run my tests from visual studio. (Extra Information: I can't see my tests on Test Explorer)

Comment: Can you post the code of one of your tests?

Comment: This is a test to see if the list is in alphebetical order "  [Then(@"the submitter company list is in alphabetical order")]
        public void ThenTheSubmitterCompanyListIsInAlphabeticalOrder()
        {
            List<string> submitterCompanyList = _currentFilingPage.SubmitterCompanyList;
            submitterCompanyList.Should().BeInAscendingOrder();
        }"

Answer (score 1):

All the Tests must have the [TestMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so MSTest/Visual Studio can find them.

- [see: MSDN Anatomy of a Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So edit your code and add the `TestMethod` to your method so it can be found as a Test. Also your method must be added inside a `TestClass`:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThenTheSubmitterCompanyListIsInAlphabeticalOrder()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am writing Functional and not Unit tests. Would the same principle still apply?

Comment: Yes. The `Type` of your test will be `UnitTest` but its purpose will be `Functional`. It's up to you what do you want to test through an automated test.. You can also use the `TestCategory` attribute to categorize your tests like `[TestCategory("Functional")]`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it and edit my tests accordingly then get back  to you.

Comment: I am now running my tests using NUnit. Thanks for the help Schaliasos